# WordPress and SQL - Update and Insert from another table if column value doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Stuck with some mysql for my wordpress site. All within 1 DB.

I am attempting to update `wp_options` table from `wp_2_options` (Multisite).

They both have `option_name` (unique_key) and `option_value` columns

It needs to update the `option_value` in the `wp_options` table if the `option_name` already exists in `wp_2_options` table

AND Insert the row from `wp_2_options` if the `option_name` doesnt exist.

So how do I `UPDATE` and `INSERT using the **UNIQUE KEY** value instead of the **PRIMARY KEY**

How do I do this?

Structure is the same for both of them

`wp_options (
  option_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  option_name varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  option_value longtext NOT NULL, 
  autoload varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes', 
  PRIMARY KEY (option_id), 
  UNIQUE KEY option_name (option_name) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1402 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

Thanks in advance

---

UPDATE:

Ended up using this INSERT then UPDATE. This worked for me.
Will just use this through PHP now.

`-- Adding completely new rows from wp_2_options into wp_options
INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_options
SELECT *
FROM wp_2_options
WHERE option_name NOT IN (SELECT option_name FROM wp_options);`

`-- Updating the option_name field in wp_options, if that got changed in wp_2_options
UPDATE wp_options JOIN wp_2_options
ON wp_options.option_name = wp_2_options.option_name
SET wp_options.option_value = wp_2_options.option_value;`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you need to do, the indexes will do the work for you.

Just do the INSERT and follow it with an UPDATE.

If it exists the INSERT will fail and the UPDATE will do the update.

If it does not exist the INSERT will put it there and the UPDATE will not affect any rows.

If I understand it correctly,
Something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `option_value`,`option_name` FROM `wp_options2` WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_options`(`option_value`,`option_name`) VALUES( '$row[0]','$row[1]')";
  mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  $sql = "UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = '$row[0]' WHERE `option_name` = '$row[1]";
  mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
```

If you need a warmer fuzzier feeling, use some error detection:

```
$sql = "SELECT `option_value`,`option_name` FROM `wp_options2` WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_options`(`option_value`,`option_name`) VALUES( '$row[0]','$row[1]')";
  mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  $rows =  mysqli_affected_rows($link);
  $sql = "UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = '$row[0]' WHERE `option_name` = '$row[1]";
  $rows +=  mysqli_affected_rows($link);
  mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  if($rows == 0) {$errors[$row[0]] = $row[1];}
}
if(count($errors) > 0){
  echo '<p>Houston, we have a problem</p><pre>';
  var_export($errors);
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very Detailed answer!! I added the code i ended up using above. INSERT then UPDATE just as you said.